# How to design a species that matches the following critera

Tags: biology, xenobiology

This is another question that seeks to provide assistance in the design of ''Eosi Humans'' an alternate human species which makes up the population of my fantasy world ''Diggoran'' ( Pronounced Die-Ah-Ran ).

At a few points in Diggoran's complex lore, certain women have experienced pregnancies in which the fetus undergoes accelerated aging and grows into a  teenager in the womb within a 9-14 months' time ( The gestational period for Eosi humans is 9-17 months ). The weight of a teenaged fetus at roughly 121 pounds combined with the greater amniotic fluid should equate to roughly 149.45 to 150 pounds of maternal weight gained during these rare pregnancies.

While this impossibly ridiculous in accordance with real-world humans, Eosi humans are capable of undergoing such pregnancies as 149.45 pounds of pregnancy weight feels like 40 pounds to them. This means that the more common pregnancies should weigh even less according to their physical perspectives. Eosi humans are also capable of carrying up to 11 children in a single pregnancy and birthing them vaginally in under 1 hour with little to no pain. ( I was previously recommended to design their pelvis like snake jaws along with other unmentioned details so that they are capable of achieving this )

Eosi humans maintain their pre-pregnancy agility during pregnancy, even in its lattermost stages. At any time during a single to octuplet pregnancy. Eosi humans should be capable of performing advanced gymnastics, athletics, heavy lifting and minimal amounts of basic self-defense. They don't ''waddle'' during pregnancy and remain largely comfortable during the entire ordeal.

Also, Eosi humans are capable of bi-gendered reproduction which means that both males and females can get pregnant but that's a whole other can of worms. Eosi Humans can do the questionable things they do because they evolved to be ''creative survivalists''. Their homeworld of ''Eos'' is a very hostile planet where all the wildlife can and may do unspeakable things to you.

Eosi humans used to be at constant risk of extinction up until 5,000 years ago when they managed to gain some level of dominance over their hostile planet.

I have been looking for a scientific way to explain the many obscure features of Eosi humans although I am the type of writer who is fully willing to say ''fuck it, let's do pure unscientific fantasy'' if the science doesn't allow for things to go my way.

I asked a previous version of this question on Reddit about a year ago and the only answer I got was ''just make them taller''. Eosi humans already stand at average heights of 6'5'' to 6'6'' and I really don't want to make them taller.

Are there any biological design techniques that I can use to make these features functional in Eosi humans? Perhaps some redesigns to their bone and muscle structures?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: then a significant part of that mass they add needs to be muscle and bone mass not baby mass. essentially they are getting swole as the pregnancy continues, the downside is they need a huge caloric intake to accomplish this.

Comment: `149.45 pounds of pregnancy weight feels like 40 pounds to them` However, if they evolved on a low-gravity world, their muscles would arguably only be equipped to carry low weight. 40 pounds would feel like 149.45 pounds to them, so 149.45 would feel like far more, unless they develop strong legs for the *sole purpose* of pregnancy.

Comment: Then I guess they should evolve on a high gravity world? @Zxyrra

Comment: @JordanTheCynic Nah, muscle strength will evolve to handle weight proportionally regardless of gravity. On a super high-gravity world, individuals will be strong but fetuses will weigh more. It doesn't matter how much gravity there is - muscles will be proportional.

Comment: @Zxyrra So none of this is scientifically possible.

Comment: Can someone chime in to elaborate on their VTC? What makes this question any more opinion-based than the average question on this site? Why does this differ from any other creature design question?

Comment: @JordanTheCynic It's not necessarily impossible. Gravity is just not part of the equation. You'll have to find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

To combat the pregnant "waddle" where their centre of mass is shifted forward, pregnant females bend the knees and lean back to compensate, have them gain some extra mass on the calves, hamstrings, glutes and lower back so that position is strong and capable of agile movement.

In addition strengthened lower pelvis muscles to minimise accidental urination, which could make them not want to take part in physical tasks if that was a worry.

Comment: Wouldn't that look pretty monstrous?

Comment: Maybe to some, I find body builder females or thick legged females quite attractive. they don't have to be so out of proportion massive, just ripped looking to show strength.

Comment: @JordanTheCynic you wont really notice the additional mass if they carry some fat, with their pregnancy weight gain you really wont notice the muscle, and they will naturally gain more hidden muscle while carrying the baby weight.

Answer (score 1):

**Eosi go from gaunt to phenomenally muscular over the course of a pregnancy.**

Nonpregnant Eosi at 6 foot 6 are gaunt, weighing in at about 130-140 lbs.  When pregnant, they add roughly the same weight as the fetus (between 11 and 88 lbs!) as muscle and fat.  6 foot 6 and 300 lbs is not outrageous.  Exaggerated abdominal and pelvic muscles help keep the uterus from shifting during gymnastics.

They cash in that weight after delivery by producing extraordinarily rich milk, dropping essentially all of the weight in the course of a year or two of breast feeding.

Comment: What would exaggerated abdominal and pelvic muscles look like? Also I've been experimenting with the idea of a pelvis that functions like a snake jaw, allowing it to open so as to make childbirth easier.